# How do you define mediatype for a boolean, a POJO and an double in retrofit?

Tags: java, android

I have a multipart form I want to upload and it is defined like this in retrofit:

```
@Multipart()
@POST("api/events/")
    Observable<Event> postEvent(@Header("Authorization") String  authHeader,@Part("venue") Venue venue,
                                @Part RequestBody image,
                                @Part RequestBody name,
                                @Part RequestBody description,
                                @Part RequestBody date,
                                @Part RequestBody type,
                                @Part RequestBody isInviteOnly,
                                @Part RequestBody isAgeRestricted,
                                @Part RequestBody isFree,
                                @Part RequestBody ticketPrice
                               );
```

The ones starting with is are boolean, ticket price is a double and Venue is a POJO.

When I try to define the mediatype using Mediatype.parse I get an error because I can't define a boolean or a POJO as "text/plain"

```
 RequestBody requestBodyinvite = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"),isInviteOnly);
        RequestBody requestBodyvenue =RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain",venue));
```

How do I parse the POJO and parameters of types other than string?

Answer (score 0):

you can parse the POJO and parameters of  media types as follows

```
 //for image
                RequestBody requestBodyMedia = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse(MULTIPART_FORM_DATA), mediaFile);
                MultipartBody.Part mediaFileToUpload = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("image", mediaFile.getName(), requestBodyMedia);
```

For primitive types it does not required to create `RequestBody` object. Primitive types can be directly send.

In you Interface

```
@Multipart()
@POST("api/events/")
Observable<Event> postEvent(
    @Part MultipartBody.Part mediaFile,
    @Part ("isFree") boolean isFree,
    @Part("ticketPrice") Double ticketPrice);
```

Comment: Will this work for all my parameters or only the image?

Comment: yup it will work for all media types. i upload video, audio and images with this formats

Comment: What about booleans, POJOs and integers?

Comment: just parse them into string. easy to handle with string for detail info follow this tutorial https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-getting-started-and-android-client

Comment: @SaurabhBhandari server won't except boolean as text/plain type

Comment: @user924 you can safely send primitive types with the request without creating requestBody. `@Part("is_final") Boolean isFinal`